# Varying performance of MSVC release exe

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++

I am curious what could be the reason for highly varying performance of the same executable.
Sometimes, I run it and it takes 20 seconds and sometimes it is 110.
Source is compiled with MSVC in Release mode with standard options.

The code is here:

```
vector<double> Un;
vector<double> Ucur;
double *pUn, *pUcur;
...
// time marching
for (old_time=time-logfreq, time+=dt; time <= end_time; time+=dt)
  {
    for (i=1, j=Un.size()-1, pUn=&Un[1], pUcur=&Ucur[1]; i < j; ++i, ++pUn, ++pUcur)
      {
        *pUcur = (*pUn)*(1.0-0.5*alpha*( *(pUn+1) - *(pUn-1) ));
      }
    Ucur[0] = (Un[0])*(1.0-0.5*alpha*( Un[1] - Un[j]   ));
    Ucur[j] = (Un[j])*(1.0-0.5*alpha*( Un[0] - Un[j-1] ));
    Un = Ucur;
  }
```

**EDIT**

Sorry not to mention input data.
The vectors Un and Ucur are initialized to 2000 elements with value 0.
No data is read/written. No interaction with console.
When I say sometimes I run it means that I have console open, no other applications running , processor throttling disabled. I keep executing application after it finishes. 
I guess it has to do with caching or something like that but I am not good on low-level things.

Comment: How consistent is the input data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved when I switched the arguments in this function from addresses to variables.
Before I had `double &time, double &dt, double &end_time`
Now: `double time, double dt, double end_time`

It appears to be memory-related issue... Hope, it helps anybody

Answer (score 1):

I would *guess* this is because you are loading a large amount of data from a storage device.  If there is a lot of contention for the storage device then things will run more slowly as your software needs to wait its turn to do some loading.